# trying to figure out how to copy thousands of files with robocopy

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am trying to move files from one server to another using Robocopy. I used my command on a directory with a few thousand files and it worked fine but now that I am trying to use it on a different folder that has has a few hundred thousand files it seems to never get started. Do you have any thoughts on what I can do to get the copies started? Maybe I need to use something other than robocopy?

```
robocopy \\remoteserver\files F:\files *.* /NP /V /MT:64
```

Comment: How long did you wait for it to do something?  It needs to build a list of which files to copy before it does anything, which will be slow on a remote server.  Run it with `/L` to see this list without copying anything.

Comment: @BACON a couple of hours

Comment: @BACON . . . do you know of a way to bypass building a list?

Comment: No, it has to calculate up-front what files match any filters and actually need to be copied before it does anything.  Is `F:` a mapped drive or a local disk?  Can you run `robocopy` on `remoteserver` to push them to wherever `F:` is?  Otherwise, I'd try something like [`Process Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to confirm it is actually doing something in the background.  I assume it is, it's just taking so long because of the sheer number of files to enumerate over a network connection.

Comment: @BACON Darn :-/ F:\ is local to the destination server. No I cannot run powershell on the remote device (synology nas without windows OS)

Comment: Are you using `robocopy` just for performance reasons?  The command line you provided isn't using any filters or other special handling, so maybe `xcopy` will suffice?  Also, did you use `*.*` to mean "all files" or "all files with a period"?  If the former, maybe try just `*` and see if that makes any difference (probably not, but perhaps there's some shortcut it can't take with `*.*` that adds up over that many files).

Comment: @Bacon Good point on the *.* I will check. I am only using robocopy for performance since I can use the multi thread option. I will look to see if I can do the same with xcopy.

Comment: @bacon xcopy was the way to go. Similar speeds and started immediately.